# ObservableCollection that fires when containing items change

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I found this topic to be a real struggle for a lot of people here and it therefore is actually covered pretty good! Nevertheless, none of the provided solutions seems to work for me.

As the title says, its about the problem that ObservableCollection doesnt fire when the value of the item changes, only if the Item **itself** gets removed, added or changed in some way.

I tried solutions with BindingList- even though a lot of people disadvice it - and it didnt work, solutions with extended ObservableCollections like it is explained [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/694370/How-to-Listen-to-Property-Chang). None of it seems to work...which leaves the question whether the error is where i think it is or somewhere completely else!!

Alright heres my code:

BaseClasses:

```
public class ModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = "")
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}

class TestSensor : ModelBase
{


    private bool isOnline;
    public bool IsOnline
    {
        get
        {
            return isOnline;
        }
        set
        {
            if (isOnline != value)
            {
                isOnline = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }


    private double sensorDatauStrain;
    public double SensorDatauStrain
    {
        get { return sensorDatauStrain; }
        set
        {
            if (sensorDatauStrain != value)
            {
                sensorDatauStrain = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }


    private double sensorDatakNewton;
    public double SensorDatakNewton
    {
        get { return sensorDatakNewton; }
        set
        {
            if (sensorDatakNewton != value)
            {
                sensorDatakNewton = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }


    private double sensorDataTon;
    public double SensorDataTon
    {
        get { return sensorDataTon; }
        set
        {
            if (sensorDataTon != value)
            {
                sensorDataTon = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }


    private double sensorDatausTon;
    public double SensorDatausTon
    {
        get { return sensorDatausTon; }
        set
        {
            if (sensorDatausTon != value)
            {
                sensorDatausTon = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private string sensorName;
    public string SensorName
    {
        get { return sensorName; }
        set
        {
            if (sensorName != value)
            {
                sensorName = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public TestSensor(string name, double ustrain,double kNewton, double ton, double uston)
    {
        this.SensorName = name;
        this.SensorDatauStrain = ustrain;
        this.SensorDatakNewton = kNewton;
        this.SensorDataTon = ton;
        this.SensorDatausTon = uston;
        this.IsOnline = true;
    }
 }
```

Then i have a class containing these Sensors:

```
class Holm : ModelBase
{
    public Holm(String Name, TestSensor sensor1, TestSensor sensor2)
    {
        Sensor1 = sensor1;
        Sensor2 = sensor2;
        this.Name = Name;
    }


    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }

        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private TestSensor sensor1;
    public TestSensor Sensor1
    {
        get
        {
            return sensor1;
        }
        set
        {
            if (sensor1 != value)
            {
                sensor1 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private TestSensor sensor2;
    public TestSensor Sensor2
    {
        get
        {
            return sensor2;
        }
        set
        {
            if (sensor2 != value)
            {
                sensor2 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }

        }
    }

    public bool IsOnline
    {
        get
        {
            if (!Sensor1.IsOnline || !Sensor2.IsOnline)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }

        }

    }

 }
```

And finally the ViewModel that contains my failing ObservableCollection - excluding some things that are not relevant:

```
    class MainViewViewModel : ModelBase
    {

           public ItemsChangeObservableCollection<Holm> HolmList { get;set;}

              public MainViewViewModel()
            {  

            Sensor11 = new TestSensor("Sensor 1.1", 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Sensor12 = new TestSensor("Sensor 1.2", 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Sensor21 = new TestSensor("Sensor 2.1", 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Sensor22 = new TestSensor("Sensor 2.2", 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Sensor31 = new TestSensor("Sensor 3.1", 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Sensor32 = new TestSensor("Sensor 3.2", 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Sensor41 = new TestSensor("Sensor 4.1", 0, 0, 0, 0);
            Sensor42 = new TestSensor("Sensor 4.2", 0, 0, 0, 0);


            Holm1 = new Holm("Holm 1", Sensor11, Sensor12);
            Holm2 = new Holm("Holm 2", Sensor21, Sensor22);
            Holm3 = new Holm("Holm 3", Sensor31, Sensor32);
            Holm4 = new Holm("Holm 4", Sensor41, Sensor42);

            HolmList = new ItemsChangeObservableCollection<Holm>();
            HolmList.Add(Holm1);
            HolmList.Add(Holm2);
            HolmList.Add(Holm3);
            HolmList.Add(Holm4);

             }


    private TestSensor sensor11;
    public TestSensor Sensor11
    {
        get { return sensor11; }
        set
        {
            if (sensor11 != value)
            {
                sensor11 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Holm1");
                this.OnPropertyChanged("HolmList");
            }
        }
    }
    private TestSensor sensor12;
    public TestSensor Sensor12
    {
        get { return sensor12; }
        set
        {
            if (sensor12 != value)
            {
                sensor12 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Holm1");
                this.OnPropertyChanged("HolmList");
            }
        }
    }



    private TestSensor sensor21;
    public TestSensor Sensor21
    {
        get { return sensor21; }
        set
        {
            if (sensor21 != value)
            {
                sensor21 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private TestSensor sensor22;
    public TestSensor Sensor22
    {
        get { return sensor22; }
        set
        {
            if (sensor22 != value)
            {
                sensor22 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();

            }
        }
    }


    private TestSensor sensor31;
    public TestSensor Sensor31
    {
        get { return sensor31; }
        set
        {
            if (sensor31 != value)
            {
                sensor31 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();

            }
        }
    }
    private TestSensor sensor32;
    public TestSensor Sensor32
    {
        get { return sensor32; }
        set
        {
            if (sensor32 != value)
            {
                sensor32 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();

            }
        }
    }


    private TestSensor sensor41;
    public TestSensor Sensor41
    {
        get { return sensor41; }
        set
        {
            if (sensor41 != value)
            {
                sensor41 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
                                }
        }
    }
    private TestSensor sensor42;
    public TestSensor Sensor42
    {
        get { return sensor42; }
        set
        {
            if (sensor42 != value)
            {
                sensor42 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
                                }
        }
    }



    private Holm holm1;
    public Holm Holm1
    {
        get
        {
            return holm1;
        }
        set
        {
            if (holm1 != value)
            {
                holm1 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
                this.OnPropertyChanged("HolmList");
            }
        }
    }

    private Holm holm2;
    public Holm Holm2
    {
        get
        {
            return holm2;
        }
        set
        {
            if (holm2 != value)
            {
                holm2 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private Holm holm3;
    public Holm Holm3
    {
        get
        {
            return holm3;
        }
        set
        {
            if (holm3 != value)
            {
                holm3 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private Holm holm4;
    public Holm Holm4
    {
        get
        {
            return holm4;
        }
        set
        {
            if (holm4 != value)
            {
                holm4 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

The Xaml isnt really important and is not yet finished. I have solved it so far with this code:

```
<CheckBox Content="Sensor1.1" IsChecked="{Binding HolmList[0].Sensor1.IsOnline}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding HolmList[0].Sensor1.IsOnline, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<CheckBox Content="Sensor1.2" IsChecked="{Binding HolmList[0].Sensor2.IsOnline}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding HolmList[0].Sensor2.IsOnline, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding HolmList[0].IsOnline, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

All i want is the  Holms IsOnline-Property to change to false as soon as one of the Sensors IsOnline-Property changes to false...but it just wouldnt!

In know this is a lot of code, but im actually not sure where the error is located. 
Also: It seems to me that my classed have redundant calls to OnPropertyChange()...but im not sure bout it.

Im really thankful for all kind of help on this!!!

Comment: Looks like what you want to achieve has nothing to do with observable collections at all. `Holm.IsOnline` depends on whether its sensors are online, so `Holm` should just listen for `IsOnline` property-change events from its sensors, and react to that by raising a property-changed event for its own `IsOnline` property.

Comment: There is no error, none of the mentioned lists/collections provide this functionality. And since your solution doesn't do it manually, your IsOnline property is correctly set. You just have to manually listen to the property-changed-event for the change of `Sensor.IsOnline`, and update the `Holm.IsOnline` accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick replies. Im not really good at the whole subscribing, unsubscribing-part yet, and therefore i would be really glad if someone could post a few lines of sample code?! I tried to go through a few tutorials but i cant figure it out properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your TextBlock that bound to `HolmList[0].IsOnline` didn't update because `IsOnline` on `Holm` didn't notify that its value changed.
You can listen to `TestSensor`'s `PropertyChanged` event in `TestSensor` and notify `IsOnline` property change when one of `TestSensor`'s `IsOnline` property change.

```
class Holm : ModelBase
{
    public Holm(String Name, TestSensor sensor1, TestSensor sensor2)
    {
        Sensor1 = sensor1;
        Sensor2 = sensor2;
        this.Name = Name;

        Sensor1.PropertyChanged += OnSensorOnlineChanged;
        Sensor2.PropertyChanged += OnSensorOnlineChanged;
    }

    private void OnSensorOnlineChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "IsOnline")
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsOnline));
        }
    }
}
```

The [nameof keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! First solution that actually works! Great help !

Comment: To avoid memory leaks there needs to be cleanup code in which you unsubscribe to `OnSensorOnlineChanged` event - as in Dbl's answer.

Comment: @NoMoreQuestions You're right.  However it also depends on scope of event producer, therefore we don't always need to unsubscribe.

Answer (score 2):

you mean something like this?

```
public class EnhancedObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public EnhancedObservableCollection(bool isCollectionChangedOnChildChange)
    {
        IsCollectionChangedOnChildChange = isCollectionChangedOnChildChange;
    }

    public EnhancedObservableCollection(List<T> list, bool isCollectionChangedOnChildChange) : base(list)
    {
        IsCollectionChangedOnChildChange = isCollectionChangedOnChildChange;
    }

    public EnhancedObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection, bool isCollectionChangedOnChildChange) : base(collection)
    {
        IsCollectionChangedOnChildChange = isCollectionChangedOnChildChange;
    }

    public bool IsCollectionChangedOnChildChange { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler<string> ChildChanged;

    protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
    {
        var item = Items[index];
        item.PropertyChanged -= ItemOnPropertyChanged;
        base.RemoveItem(index);
    }

    private void ItemOnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var handler = ChildChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, propertyChangedEventArgs.PropertyName);
        }
        if (IsCollectionChangedOnChildChange)
        {
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace));
        }
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
        item.PropertyChanged += ItemOnPropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But the result is the same like with the solution i linked in the question: It looks like exactly what i need...but somehow doesnt work! The value of HolmList[0].IsOnline doesnt change...
Is there a reason you did not overwrite the add-method?

Comment: @Laurence i usually override insert, because some collections offer add to append to a list at the end or insert at a specific position. overriding inserItem will be called in both cases. usually i go to sources to make sure though :)